# Python concurrent.futures - Process steady memory increae

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I built a program with concurrent.futures ProcessPoolExecutor. It works great and I found a nice framework that manages the queue size. Since the number of total items to process can be tens of thousands, i limited the queue size to a little more than the amount of workers to save on a bit of memory usage and process time for adding all items to queue in the beginning.

The problem im having is that the workers keep increasing memory usage over time. I expect the main process to do so, as its saving the results. However, the workers should release their memory after a process is finished. I see that workers can get like 500mb in memory usage. With 16 workers, that gets big very fast.

I would like for someone to guide me into how i can make sure my program never exceeds memory. Or how i can fix the workers so they don't keep increasing memory usage. I tried things to help reduce memory usage, like: using iterables, deleting variables. It doesnt seem to work.

My program often uses 100% cpu in the beginning, but fizzles out a bit over time.
Memory climbs over time, but sometimes it dips.

Also, how much memory can i expect a program like this to take? With like 20.000 items in total, every one of them being a file thats being read. Each one returns a decent size array. Right now i notice it using like 7GB after 1000 files.
When i use some tool to see how much memory the big array variable costs, its like a few MB tops. So i wonder where the rest comes from.

Thanks for answering, code and screenshots below.

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=cpu_count()) as executor:
    futures = {}
    files = iter(files)

    while total - count:
        try:
            for file in files:
                future = executor.submit(process_file, file)
                futures[future] = file

                if len(futures) > cpu_count() + 2:
                    break
            
            for future in as_completed(futures):
                count += 1

                process_results(future.result())

                del futures[future]
                break

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

[Memory usage in the beginning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueasF.png)
[Memory usage after some time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxV41.png)

Comment: Sum up whatever this is you have a question about and focus on asking one specific question. Hints:

For this post and future ones.

1. Shorter texts
2. Clear and concise texts
3. Make sure both title and text are coherent and mereological to one another

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. My current workaround is to split the data into smaller chunks and then process these sequentially, with a separate ProcessPoolExecutor created for each of them. In this way, the additional memory is freed whenever the previous pool goes out of scope. Of course, this means that before the next chunk is processed, all items in the current chunk need to be finished, leading to potential bottlenecks. Time overhead isn't too bad in my case, the code is just a lot uglier. Would be great to find a real solution!